# easeljs in ionic2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, createjs

```
import * as easeljs from 'createjs-easeljs';
```

gives out the following:

```
Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'createjs-easeljs'.
```

I have installed createjs-easeljs via npm install and the easeljs typings.

I have the following typings:

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "globalDependencies": {
   "createjs-lib": "registry:dt/createjs-lib#0.0.0+20160317120654",
   "easeljs": "registry:dt/easeljs#0.8.0+20160919062420",
   "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160602141504",
   "tweenjs": "registry:dt/tweenjs#0.6.0+20160317120654"
}
```

.

```
import * as easeljs from 'easeljs';
```

Gives the same error.

Comment: Which version of ionic? cause if its the new one you can't use typings and gotta install with npm install @types

Comment: @misha130 thanks, i used @ types now but I ran into other problems

Comment: Remove * as easeljs and just import easeljs from ...

Comment: @misha130 I now have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786189/ionic2-typing-reference-error